# Assignment inside two for loops

Tags: rcpp

I am trying to build a specific matrix but using simply R can take a lot of time considering the size of the entries that I have to use. I write a function in Rcpp with the Armadillo functionality because I need the linear algebra part to work with matrices. My code is the next:

```
library('Rcpp')
library('inline')
library('RcppArmadillo')

cppFunction("arma::mat GramMat(arma::mat A, double parametro, int n) {
            arma::mat resultado=A;
            double temp;
            for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
              for (int j=i; j<n; j++){
                  resultado(j,i)= exp(-1*parametro*((A.col(i)-A.col(j)).t() * (A.col(i)-A.col(j))));
              }
            }
            for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
              for (int j=0; j<i; j++){
                resultado(i,j)=resultado(j,i);
              }
            }
            return resultado;}",depends="RcppArmadillo")
```

and I am getting the next error:

```
               temp= exp(-1*parametro*((A.col(i)-A.col(j)).t() * (A.col(i)-A.col(j))));
                   ^
make: *** [file548914af6578.o] Error 1
```

The problem is with the assignation, because I tried assigning just a 1 and the assignation is working well. And I tought that maybe the problem was with the right hand side but I print it with Rcout and is delivering well number.

Comment: The error message you show may not correspond to the source code you showed as there is no assignment to `temp` in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried compiling your code, I saw a more informative error message:

> file2f78133e7bc2.cpp: In function ‘arma::mat GramMat(arma::mat,
>   double, int)’: file2f78133e7bc2.cpp:14:99: error: cannot convert
>   ‘arma::enable_if2,
>   arma::subview_col, arma::eglue_minus>, arma::op_htrans>,
>   arma::eGlue, arma::subview_col,
>   arma::eglue_minus>, arma::glue_times>, arma::eop_scalar_times>,
>   arma::eop_exp> >::result {aka const
>   arma::eOp,
>   arma::subview_col, arma::eglue_minus>, arma::op_htrans>,
>   arma::eGlue, arma::subview_col,
>   arma::eglue_minus>, arma::glue_times>, arma::eop_scalar_times>,
>   arma::eop_exp>}’ to ‘double’ in assignment
>                      resultado(j,i)= exp(-1*parametro*((A.col(i)-A.col(j)).t() * (A.col(i)-A.col(j))));
>                                                                                                      ^ make: *** [file2f78133e7bc2.o] Error 1

This leads us directly to the problem; the operation

```
(A.col(i)-A.col(j)).t() * (A.col(i)-A.col(j))
```

returns a type that cannot be directly converted to a double. However, we can just use `arma::as_scalar()` to fix this (see [here](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#as_scalar) in the Armadillo documentation); the following compiled fine for me:

```
cppFunction("arma::mat GramMat(arma::mat A, double parametro, int n) {
            arma::mat resultado=A;
            double temp;
            for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
              for (int j=i; j<n; j++){
                  resultado(j,i)= arma::as_scalar(exp(-1*parametro*((A.col(i)-A.col(j)).t() * (A.col(i)-A.col(j)))));
              }
            }
            for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
              for (int j=0; j<i; j++){
                resultado(i,j)=resultado(j,i);
              }
            }
            return resultado;}",depends="RcppArmadillo")
```

There are quite a few other things that could be improved in this code, of course. For example, as [Dirk Eddelbuettel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143305/dirk-eddelbuettel) points out, you actually never use `temp` in your code. You might also want to use `arma::dot()` to get the dot product of `(A.col(i)-A.col(j))` with itself (see [here](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#dot) in the Armadillo documentation -- as `arma::dot()` returns a double, it would also eliminate the need to use `arma::as_scalar()`), etc.

Comment: Yep, and it is 2018 so we really want Rcpp Attributes and `cppFunction()` instead of the old inline package.

Comment: Thanks I was thinking that the problem was that casting, but I was just following some presentation that I found, haven't checked the documentation directly. Yes I am thinking in improving the code,I forgot to erase the temp variable.

Comment: Yeah I am having a trouble reading directly with Attributes it's seems a problem from the path where the Armadillo library is stored, and the inline worked well. I would try the issue with the library later, thanks.